# Upload Image Files to a Ruby on Rails JSON API with Carrierwave

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, file, http, carrierwave

I have a Ruby on Rails JSON API, that is supposed to take HTTP-Requests with both, JSON-data and files within one reuqest. Therefore I installed the gem Carrierwave.
When I start a Request with Python, which looks like the following:

```
url = [...]
headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

payload = {
    'image': {
        'name': 48,
        'camera_name': 'test',
        'image_info': {
            'iso': '1:100',
            'shutter': '21:1/250',
            'aperture': '5:3.2'
        }
    }
}

files = {
    'image': open('C:\\Users\\Mfaorlkzus\\Desktop\\_DSC1036.jpg', 'rb')
}

print('uploading database object...')
r = requests.post(url, files=files data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r)
print(str(r.text.encode('utf-8')))
```

... the Request fails because of some formatting errors. The Output on the console looks like this:

```
Started POST "/images/1?token=[...]" for [...] at 2017-11-06 13:18:12 +0100

Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError (invalid %-encoding ("image"

name
--8038f415e00d4695aa798709c31b44ff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

camera_name
--8038f415e00d4695aa798709c31b44ff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

image_info
--8038f415e00d4695aa798709c31b44ff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="_DSC1036.jpg"

▒▒▒▒JFIF,,▒▒▒ExifMM*
▒
▒▒(1▒2܇i▒0▒▒2$▒4D\NIKON CORPORATIONNIKON D7100,,paint.net 4.0.92017:03:27 22:25:31#▒▒▒▒▒▒▒"▒'d▒0230▒▒▒▒▒
Ғڒ
▒▒▒     ▒
▒50▒▒50▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒(▒▒▒       ▒
▒
2017:03:11 07:01:222017:03:11 07:01:22A▒B@
                                          ▒▒▒▒▒▒,
▒
▒R▒▒R▒4365366▒

#
8
18.0-105.0 mm f/3.5-5.6▒(HH▒▒
XICC_PROFILE
HLinomntrRGB XYZ ▒      1acspMSFTIEC sRGB▒▒▒-HP  cprtP3desc▒lwtpt▒bkptrXYZgXYZ,bXYZ@dmndTpdmdd▒▒vuedL▒view▒$lumi▒meas
$tech0
rTRC<
gTRC<
bTRC<
textCopyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard CompanydescsRGB IEC61966-2.1sRGB IEC61966-2.1XYZ ▒Q▒XYZ XYZ o▒8▒▒XYZ b▒▒▒▒XYZ $▒▒▒▒descIEC http://www.iec.chIEC http://www.iec.chdesc.IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB.IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGBdesc,Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1,Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1view▒▒_.▒▒▒
                \▒XYZ L VPW▒meas▒sig CRT curv
%+28>ELRY`gnu|▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
)):
```

and further:

```
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:72:in `rescue in parse_nested_query'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/query_parser.rb:61:in `parse_nested_query'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:468:in `parse_query'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:343:in `POST'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:355:in `block (2 levels) in POST'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:80:in `block in parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:80:in `fetch'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:80:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:354:in `block in POST'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:353:in `POST'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:45:in `parameters'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:41:in `filtered_parameters'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:21:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.0.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I'm really running out of ideas. It would be cool if you can get me some tips on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to convert the file in to binary in Request and use carrierwave-base64 convert back

Comment: Thank you, and how can I access/convert the files within Rails?

Comment: And do you have a guide to convert files to binary please? I'm completely new to Python and haven't found anything suiting yet.

Comment: Are you working in python or ruby on rails?

Comment: I'm using Python to upload an image from my hard drive to a Ruby on Rails API on a Server

Answer (score 0):

I think is missing comma `r = requests.post(url, files=files data=payload, headers=headers)` between `files=files, data=...`

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo. It's correct in my code

Answer (score 0):

Use [carrierwave-base64](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64) to Upload files encoded as base64 to carrierwave

Once you configure CarrierWave and CarrierWave-Base64, as well as fog, the next step is to process the received image and upload it to S3. Add the following methods in your controller:

```
def split_base64(uri_str)
          if uri_str.match(%r{^data:(.*?);(.*?),(.*)$})
            uri = Hash.new
            uri[:type] = $1 # "image/gif"
            uri[:encoder] = $2 # "base64"
            uri[:data] = $3 # data string
            uri[:extension] = $1.split('/')[1] # "gif"
            return uri
          else
            return nil
          end
end

def convert_data_uri_to_upload(obj_hash)
          if obj_hash[:image_url].try(:match, %r{^data:(.*?);(.*?),(.*)$})
            image_data = split_base64(obj_hash[:image_url])
            image_data_string = image_data[:data]
            image_data_binary = Base64.decode64(image_data_string)

            temp_img_file = Tempfile.new("")
            temp_img_file.binmode
            temp_img_file << image_data_binary
            temp_img_file.rewind

            img_params = {:filename => "image.#{image_data[:extension]}", :type => image_data[:type], :tempfile => temp_img_file}
            uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(img_params)

            obj_hash[:image] = uploaded_file
            obj_hash.delete(:image_url)
          end
    return obj_hash    
end
```

Your request should be like

example:

```
{
 "user":{
         "name": "John Doe",
         "image_url": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJEAAAAAAP////8AAP///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAABAAEAAAICVAEAOw=="
        }   
}
```

The image_url parameter should contain the Base64-encoded image, in the format above.

Next, in your controller's create method:

```
def create
        @user = User.new(convert_data_uri_to_upload(user_params))

        if @user.save
            render status: 200, json: {
                message: "Successfully added user with ID: " + @user.id.to_s,
                image_url: @user.image_url
            }
        else
            render status: 422, json:{
                errors: @user.errors
            }.to_json
        end
end
```

If you find any difficulty please add in comment section or follow below

https://sebastiandobrincu.com/blog/how-to-upload-images-to-rails-api-using-s3

Comment: Thank you. But is it necessary to convert the image in base64 before uploading? I mean the purpose of Carrierwave is to get rid of base64 decoding.